# I installed coc-snippets for my vim, but it has an error on execute python file

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin

[image]

I am trying to use the coc-snippets for my vim, but it has a warning every time I start it, the snippets are working but just want to disable the warning, I set the coc warning disabled already. I am using wsl2 ubuntu, I also tried it on my raspberry pi, it is good on raspberryos.

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should install a other version python